# NSExpression and Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am at beginner level for Core Data. I am  creating an app which can calculate expenses bared by each member of the house. I have an Entity named "Expenses" and properties are

1. payer
2. date
3. amt (amount)
4. desc (description)

How do I create an array using NSExpression or any other way which can return Total of expense amount for each payer.

P.S. = I can get the 'sum' of 'amt' for specific string by following code

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amt"];

NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];


NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc]init];    


NSString *mem = @"Chintu";


predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:

             @"payer like %@", mem];

[expressionDescription setName:@"sumExpenses"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:expression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```